# How do I link from a webpage to a PDF file in media, without getting a big media icon?

Tags: urls

I have some PDFs in my media folder and I want to link them to a webpage, with an ordinary link, not a big icon. Basically I need to get the url, but although it pops up when I click on the PDF, I can't see how to copy and paste. The only way is to write it down. Must be an easier way?

Comment: Which part of this is WordPress related?  Sorry, not sure what the context here is.  Is this in the Block Editor, Classic Editor, a third-party page builder?
The easiest thing I can think of is to go to the Media Library, click on the document and then on the right hand side of the screen locate the file URL and click 'Copy to Clipboard', then create a link the way you normally would in the block editor, classic editor or third-party page builder and paste the URL you copied from the media library.